# Заполнение JTable из массива

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Помогите, пожалуйста, пробежаться по циклу и заполнить таблицу JTable данными из массива:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        JTable table;

        Person person = new Person();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        String[] col = {"Id", "Name", "Lname", "Age"};

        String[][] data = {{String.valueOf(person.id), person.fName, person.lName, String.valueOf(person.age)}};

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            //тут нужна помощь
        }

        table = new JTable(data, col);    
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);        
        add(table);    

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Класс **Person**:

```
//Person
class Person{
    static int id;
    String fName;
    String lName;
    int age;

    public Person(){
    }

    public Person(int id, String fName, String lName, int age) {
        init(id, fName, lName, age);
    }

    public void init(int id, String fName, String lName, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.age   = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id +
            ", fName=" + fName + 
            ", lName=" + lName + 
            ", age=" + age + "]";
    }


    public static int getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lName;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Класс **Main**:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        public static ArrayList<Person> init() {
            ArrayList<Person> pp = new ArrayList<Person>();

            pp.add(new Person(1, "vasia", "Pupkin", 19) );
            pp.add(new Person(2, "Maxim", "Ivanovko", 20) );
            pp.add(new Person(3, "Ilya", "Gupkin", 21) );
            pp.add(new Person(4, "Masha", "Karinina", 22) );
            pp.add(new Person(5, "Maxim", "Hupkin", 23) );

            pp.add(new Person(6, "Maxim", "Kusow", 31) );
            pp.add(new Person(7, "Anya", "Lizunova", 32) );
            pp.add(new Person(33, "Veronika", "Sharowa", 33) );
            pp.add(new Person(9, "Ulya", "Jorova", 34) );
            pp.add(new Person(10, "Korova", "Barinova", 35) );

            pp.add(new Person(11, "Igor", "Kusow", 41) );
            pp.add(new Person(12, "Anya", "Lizunova", 42) );
            pp.add(new Person(13, "Veronika", "Sharowa", 43) );
            pp.add(new Person(14, "Arish", "Suka", 44) );
            pp.add(new Person(15, "Karina", "Baranova", 45) );

            pp.add(new Person(16, "Marina", "Sereda", 11) );
            pp.add(new Person(17, "natasha", "Rogaleva", 12) );
            pp.add(new Person(18, "Bogdan", "Emetz", 13) );
            pp.add(new Person(19, "Maxim", "Grechko", 14) );
            pp.add(new Person(20, "Natya ", "Sisoewa", 15) );

            pp.add(new Person(21, "Nastya ", "Nisoewa", 16 ));

            return pp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код класса `Person` в вопрос, отредактировав его.

Comment: И что надо? Двадцать раз одно и того же вывести? Или разных людей запхать в data? Объявляете data размером нужным `final int size = 20;` и  `String[][] data = new String[size][4];` а потом в цикле пихаете

Comment: У меня есть  ArrayList<Person> pp = new ArrayList<Person>(); в котором 20 персон. Ими нужно заполнить.

Comment: @МаксимДемьянюк нда? И где этот лист? Что-то его не видно...... видно только `String[][] data = {{String.valueOf(person.id), person.fName, person.lName, String.valueOf(person.age)}};
`........ и заполнить что? `data`? так как его заполните если вы его уже объявили и инициализировали не пойми чем) ....нужно больше информации

Comment: Я дополнил. Этот лист в Main`e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем

- В классе `Person` уберите `static` у `id` и у метода `getid()`. Она не будет принадлежать персоне индивидуально и каждая последующая персона будет перезатирать его.
- непонятная конструкция: `String[][] data = {{String.valueOf(person.id), person.fName, person.lName, String.valueOf(person.age)}};` не нужна вообще.

  Потому, что:
- Например вы получаете свою коллекцию персон

  ```
  ArrayList<Person> myPersons = init();
  ```

  И далее можете спокойно инициализировать массив с нужным размером:

  ```
  String[][] data = new String[myPersons.size()][col.length];
  ```

  В итоге останется в цикле данные добавить:

  ```
  int i = 0;
  for (Person myPerson : myPersons) {
      data[i][0] = String.valueOf(myPerson.getid());
      data[i][1] = myPerson.fName;
      data[i][2] = myPerson.lName;
      data[i][3] = String.valueOf(myPerson.age);
      i++;
  }
  ```

  и засунуть в таблицу

  ```
  table = new JTable(data, col);
  ```

Comment: Привет, поможешь мне с аналогичной проблемой? совсем запутался.. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1085998